# Remove all elements of a string list in python if they contain a given phrase

Tags: python, json, string, list, object

Have a list called `summary` containing a corresponding JSON object similar to:

```
{
   # summary[0]
   "object1": {
      "json_data": "{json data information}",
      "tables_data": "TABLES_DATA"
   },

   # summary[1]
   "object2": {
      "json_data": "{json data information}",
      "tables_data": ""
   }
}
```

Essentially, if `"tables_data": ""` is found within the string of a list item, I want the entire list item to be removed.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a dictionary-comprehension selecting the dictionary item with `'tables_data'` has a value not equals `''`:

```
summary = [{
   # summary[0]
   "object1": {
      "json_data": "{json data information}",
      "tables_data": "TABLES_DATA"
   },

   # summary[1]
   "object2": {
      "json_data": "{json data information}",
      "tables_data": ""
   }
}]
result = [{k: d for k, d in s.items() if d.get('tables_data') != ''} for s in summary]
# [{'object1': {'json_data': '{json data information}', 'tables_data': 'TABLES_DATA'}}]
```

Comment: I don't have a dictionary and have a list though, so my object doesn't have the ```items``` attribute

Comment: Use: `results = [{k: d for k, d in summary[0].items() if d.get('tables_data') != ''}]`.

Comment: Tried this and it looks like only my first object remains in the JSON file

Comment: Please edit your question to include exact view of json. Looks like you want to iterate list, but let's see.

Comment: It's essentially what I have on the post. The entire file has too much information to include

Comment: Okay. Let's see the edit is working. Can you try again?

Comment: also out of curiosity, how would I be able to also remove the entire object if the ```json_data``` information is empty? Tried adding another if clause but didn't work

Comment: Tried that already but adding the or clause doesn't remove anything for some reason

Comment: It should be `and`. - `and d.get('json_data') != ''`